# Ubuntu 17.04 live USB, stuck in tty tests loop

Tags: boot, live-usb, mac, refind

I'm trying to use a live USB of Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on my 2013 Mac Pro (trash can model).  But I'm getting stuck in a loop during the text output during the booting process.

I have rEFInd set up (since I'm already running 16.04), and I select the USB drive to boot into Grub.  I select boot from USB.  I see the logo animate for a bit, which I'm guessing is gnome or gdm related.  Then I get the following output on the screen in TTY (with times ommitted):

```
bmca: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
bmca: bus0: No SPROM available
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I can see the output disappear and reappear frequently, like it's getting stuck in a loop.  I've searched these error messages, and they suggest disabling WiFi since it could be a driver issue.  But I'm using rEFInd, which I don't think has that option.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you boot an Ubuntu installation USB drive from rEFInd, chances are it's launching GRUB, so you can do anything you'd do in GRUB. If you launch a kernel directly, you can hit F2, Insert, or Tab twice to get to a simple line editor that you use to edit kernel options.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the initial problem:  If you boot using USB, edit the GRUB entry for booting to live.  Under the linux command, add nomodeswitch as a parameter.  There seems to be an issue with the video drivers on this computer.

However once it's installed, I still need the nomodeswitch parameter or else Ubuntu won't boot.  Currently trying to figure this out.

Comment: I've never used it (I hate GRUB), but [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) is said to be helpful for editing GRUB's options. This really just helps you edit files in `/etc/grub.d` and `/etc/default/grub`, so you could edit the appropriate file directly -- I think it would be the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`, but I'm not positive of that. You'd then need to run `sudo update-grub` to activate your changes. You can do the same thing with most boot loaders by editing their configuration files, but details vary depending on the boot loader.

Comment: Oh, I missed in the original question that you're using rEFInd. If you launch your kernels directly from rEFInd, you can edit `/boot/refind_linux.conf` to add the `nomodeswitch` option. If that file isn't present, run `mkrlconf` from Ubuntu. (This script comes with rEFInd, but might not be installed in Ubuntu if you installed rEFInd from OS X.)